# Gunicorn freezes intermittently

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have a Django project served via gunicorn. Unfortunately gunicorn freezes intermittently, sometimes after a few days of running, sometimes within hours of restarting. The weird thing is that I use the same configuration on 4 of my servers, all running **different code**, and they all experience the **outage at the same time**.

The following are my config files:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

---

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn Daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/opt/app_repo
Restart=always
ExecStart=/opt/app_repo/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile /opt/app_repo/gunicorn.access.log \
          --error-logfile /opt/app_repo/gunicorn.error.log \
          --timeout 1000 \
          --workers 9 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          --log-level DEBUG \
          --capture-output \
          app_repo.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

... I was able to confirm the Gunicorn freezing by running the following commands:

```
$ systemctl status caddy # -> up and running, curl-ing to the website's URL without a slash will return a Caddy redirect to its slashed version
$ systemctl status gunicorn # -> up and running as well
$ curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock http:// # this hangs between 2-45 minutes, in which at this point the server is responsive again
```

Versions:

```
gunicorn==19.9.0
Django==2.2.3
```

... note that I also tried updating to the latest gunicorn version, but I had the same issue so I reverted back. Things that I also tried:

1. Daily scheduled reboot
2. Testing both nginx and caddy as the reverse proxy
3. Checking for oom errors (`dmesg -T | egrep -i 'memory'`, `dmesg -T | egrep -i 'oom'`) in which I didn't find anything gunicon related.

Comment: Do all of the servers use some shared resource such as a database, a disk system, ...?

Comment: @AKX kind of, the three servers connect to the fourth one as their API, and then the API server connects to an RDS instance for persistent storage.

Comment: Well, have you looked at the RDS metrics?

Comment: I actually haven't, will do now. But what I have found out is that while I'm changing the API server's instance type (thus stopping) it, one of the server freezes as well. I think the outage revolves around the API's gunicorn freezing, but what's interesting is why does the other servers freeze as well when it should've just thrown a timeout error.